# Добавить cookie в Selenium. Как решить ошибку при добавлении?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cookie

**Update:** Вывел в отдельный вопрос без лишнего. Понял что проблема именно в методе add_cookie(). [Ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/894367/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-selenium-driver-add-cookie-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83)

Пожалуйста помогите разобраться, что я делаю неправильно.
Я выполняю аутентификацию на сайте с помощью Selenium и вывожу куки.

```
driver.get(url='https://vk.com/login')
email = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
pass_ = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
email.send_keys("mail@main.ru")
pass_.send_keys("12345678")
driver.find_element_by_id("login_button").click()
print(driver.get_cookies())
```

**Вывод:**

```
[{'name': 'remixlang', 'value': '0', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.vk.com', 'secure': False, 'httpOnly': False, 'expiry': 15701242142714017}, {'name': 'remixstid', 'value': '542957824_fewfeffew62864811b8edew418ff', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.vk.com', 'secure': False, 'httpOnly': False, 'expiry': 15716013234721}, {'name': 'remixlhk', 'value': '357eec0wefew1e8eaeec732', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.vk.com', 'secure': False, 'httpOnly': False, 'expiry': 15710123351437}, {'name': 'remixflash', 'value': '0.0.0', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.vk.com', 'secure': False, 'httpOnly': False, 'expiry': 15423232368517}, {'name': 'remixscreen_depth', 'value': '24', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.vk.com', 'secure': False, 'httpOnly': False, 'expiry': 1573231312517}, {'name': 'remixgp', 'value': '877dw5375795573232gg3f04b6e76fcb3299f3d1', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.vk.com', 'secure': True, 'httpOnly': False, 'expiry': 1540381324318}, {'name': 'remixdt', 'value': '7200', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.vk.com', 'secure': False, 'httpOnly': False, 'expiry': 12341571312518}, {'name': 'remixjsp', 'value': '%7B%22id%22%3A%22jnd36lyw.988%22%2C%22loc%22%3A%22https%3A//vk.com/login%22%2C%22events%22%3A%5B%5B%22domComplete%22%2C3298%2Cnull%2C%22unknown%22%2C%2217024%22%5D%2C%5wefw21234efwB%22domContentLowdweadedEvwefentEnd%22%2C2618%2Cnull%2C%wefwefewew22unknown%22%2C%2217024%22%5Dfewew%2C%5B%22loadEventEnd%22%2C3301%2Cnull%2C%22unknown%22%2C%2217024%22%5D%5D%7D', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.vk.com', 'secure': False, 'httpOnly': False, 'expiry': 1539123214777383}]
```

При следующем запуске, **я хочу передать куки** и не выполнять аутентификацию снова. Для этого я сохраняю список с куками из вывода в переменную и пытаюсь передать в Selenium

```
cookies = [{'name': 'remixlang', 'value': '0', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.vk.com', 'secure': False, 'httpOnly': False, 'expiry': 15701242142714017}, {'name': 'remixstid', 'value': '542957824_fewfeffew62864811b8edew418ff', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.vk.com', 'secure': False, 'httpOnly': False, 'expiry': 15716013234721}, {'name': 'remixlhk', 'value': '357eec0wefew1e8eaeec732', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.vk.com', 'secure': False, 'httpOnly': False, 'expiry': 15710123351437}, {'name': 'remixflash', 'value': '0.0.0', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.vk.com', 'secure': False, 'httpOnly': False, 'expiry': 15423232368517}, {'name': 'remixscreen_depth', 'value': '24', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.vk.com', 'secure': False, 'httpOnly': False, 'expiry': 1573231312517}, {'name': 'remixgp', 'value': '877dw5375795573232gg3f04b6e76fcb3299f3d1', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.vk.com', 'secure': True, 'httpOnly': False, 'expiry': 1540381324318}, {'name': 'remixdt', 'value': '7200', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.vk.com', 'secure': False, 'httpOnly': False, 'expiry': 12341571312518}, {'name': 'remixjsp', 'value': '%7B%22id%22%3A%22jnd36lyw.988%22%2C%22loc%22%3A%22https%3A//vk.com/login%22%2C%22events%22%3A%5B%5B%22domComplete%22%2C3298%2Cnull%2C%22unknown%22%2C%2217024%22%5D%2C%5wefw21234efwB%22domContentLowdweadedEvwefentEnd%22%2C2618%2Cnull%2C%wefwefewew22unknown%22%2C%2217024%22%5Dfewew%2C%5B%22loadEventEnd%22%2C3301%2Cnull%2C%22unknown%22%2C%2217024%22%5D%5D%7D', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.vk.com', 'secure': False, 'httpOnly': False, 'expiry': 1539123214777383}]
for cookie in cookies:
     driver.add_cookie({'cookie': cookie})
```

Но на последней строчке я получаю **ошибку**:

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: missing field `name` at line 1 column 150

Пожалуйста помогите разобраться в проблеме. Спасибо огромное заранее, как всегда!

**Дополнение:**
На строку

```
driver.add_cookie({'name' : 'foo', 'value' : 'bar'})
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       driver.add_cookie({'name' : 'foo', 'value' : 'bar'})
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 894, in add_cookie
>       self.execute(Command.ADD_COOKIE, {'cookie': cookie_dict})
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   **selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidCookieDomainException: Message: Document is cookie-averse**

**Пробовал использовать CromeWebDriver:**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.add_cookie({'name' : 'foo', 'value' : 'bar'})
```

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unable to set cookie
>     (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)

Ума не приложу в чем проблема...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Нашел решение!**
Оказывается, что бы добавить куки в Selenium нужно, сначала обратиться к странице, а потом уже добавлять куки. При следующем обращении к странице куки будут уже добавлены.

```
driver.get(url='https://vk.com/login')
driver.add_cookie({'name' : 'foo', 'value' : 'bar'})
driver.get(url='https://vk.com/login')
```

Answer (score 2):

В `add_cookie` просто добавляйте словарь-cookie, изменив строку на:

```
driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

---

Без цикла это, к примеру, было бы:

```
driver.add_cookie({'name': 'remixlang', 'value': '0', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.vk.com', 'secure': False, 'httpOnly': False, 'expiry': 15701242142714017})
```

---

Примеры из документации метода [add_cookie](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/18681a6c1b59434f2639c2c56383a58f1118f009/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py#L880):

```
driver.add_cookie({'name' : 'foo', 'value' : 'bar'})
driver.add_cookie({'name' : 'foo', 'value' : 'bar', 'path' : '/'})
driver.add_cookie({'name' : 'foo', 'value' : 'bar', 'path' : '/', 'secure':True})
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за предложенный вариант. Расширил вопрос, на данный метод я получаю ошибку selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidCookieDomainException: Message: Document is cookie-averse

Comment: @DmitrySharko, есть подозрение что это из-за того что домен в куке не совпадает с доменом ссылки. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Errors/InvalidCookieDomain / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48352380/ /

Comment: Мб, вам это решение поможет: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48354207/5909792

Comment: Большое спасибо за предложенные варианты, но конкретно у меня не в этом оказывается проблема. Я понял что у меня почему то не работает нормально сам метод add_cookie(). Вывел в отдельный вопрос, ибо проблема именно в этом.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/894367/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-selenium-driver-add-cookie-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83