# Не могу добавить куки в Selenium. driver.add_cookie() возвращает ошибку

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Проблема банальная, но как ее решить я не понимаю - **получаю ошибки на стандартный метод add_cookie()**. Пожалуйста помогите!

**Ввод с Firefox WebDriver:**

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.add_cookie({'name': 'remixlang', 'value': '0'})
```

**Вывод:**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidCookieDomainException: Message: Document is cookie-averse
```

**Ввод с Chrome WebDriver:**

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.add_cookie({'name': 'remixlang', 'value': '0'})
```

**Вывод:**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unable to set cookie
(Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 
(7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 
x86_64)
```

Кроме метода add_cookie() все работает отлично. Selenium и WebDriver`а последних версий, пробывал даже другой разрядности качать... Пожалуйста подскажите варианты решения проблемы! Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Думаю, сначала нужно что-нибудь загрузить (`driver.get(url=`), а потом добавлять куки, в общем как тут: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48354207/5909792

Comment: @gil9red Это абсолютно правильное решение! Я разобрался в этом еще вчера, но не успел оставить ответ в этой ветке.(вчера оставил только в прошлой) В любом случае большое спасибо за помощь!

Вот ответ с примером: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/894399/295128

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Нашел решение!**
Оказывается, что бы добавить куки в Selenium нужно, сначала обратиться к странице, а потом уже добавлять куки. При следующем обращении к странице куки будут уже добавлены.

```
driver.get(url='https://vk.com/login')
driver.add_cookie({'name' : 'foo', 'value' : 'bar'})
driver.get(url='https://vk.com/login')
```