# Не работает импорт куки в Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, cookie, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

После авторизации на Фейсбуке получил куки через метод `driver.get_cookies()`

Вывод:

```
[{'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1609944355, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'fr', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': '19KsJJcu9iZcNDw80.AWUnObiYyWlbmsSbMaAoTBQ3Qkg.BffyYn.EY.AAA.0.0.BffyYq.AWWxZSl5V8s'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1633704358, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'xs', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': '4%3A8K8IO-G4AqVxpw%3A2%3A1602168362%3A-1%3A-1'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1633704358, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'c_user', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': '100055628751137'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1665240357, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'datr', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': 'JyZ_X5OBe55yRMjKU-d8nSYQ'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1602773165, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'dpr', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': '1.25'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1602258362, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'spin', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': 'r.1002790228_b.trunk_t.1602168365_s.1_v.2_'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1602773164, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'wd', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'Lax', 'secure': True, 'value': '1036x684'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1665240361, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'sb', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': 'JyZ_XwAJTQy5L-W6Ivkp2MBC'}]
```

Потом сохранил их в переменную `cookies` и при попытке импортировать куки через метод `driver.add_cookie()` получаю исключение:

```
InvalidArgumentException
Message: invalid argument: missing 'cookie'
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)
```

Код:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://facebook.com')

cookies = "[{'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1609944355, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'fr', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': '19KsJJcu9iZcNDw80.AWUnObiYyWlbmsSbMaAoTBQ3Qkg.BffyYn.EY.AAA.0.0.BffyYq.AWWxZSl5V8s'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1633704358, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'xs', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': '4%3A8K8IO-G4AqVxpw%3A2%3A1602168362%3A-1%3A-1'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1633704358, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'c_user', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': '100055628751137'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1665240357, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'datr', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': 'JyZ_X5OBe55yRMjKU-d8nSYQ'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1602773165, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'dpr', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': '1.25'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1602258362, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'spin', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': 'r.1002790228_b.trunk_t.1602168365_s.1_v.2_'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1602773164, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'wd', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'Lax', 'secure': True, 'value': '1036x684'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1665240361, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'sb', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': 'JyZ_XwAJTQy5L-W6Ivkp2MBC'}]"

driver.add_cookie(cookies)
driver.get('https://facebook.com')
```

Пробовал добавлять в цикле:

```
for cookie in cookies:
  driver.add_cookie({'cookie' : cookie})
```

Ничего не помогает... Что я делаю не так?

PS: [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663666/), [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/894367/) и [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/894287/) я уже смотрел, однако спасения в этом не обнаружил :(

Comment: А вы уверены, что ошибка возникает именно в этой строчке кода? Возможно вы где-то ещё используете этот метод?

Comment: Нет, нигде больше не использую