# Добавление cookies в selenium для другого домена

Tags: python, selenium

Как я уже понял из другого ответа: 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/894399/364213
в selenium можно добавлять cookie, только находясь на странце домена

К примеру если cookie вида:

```
{'domain': 'drive.google.com', 'expirationDate': 12345, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'rive.google.com', 'path': '/drive', 'secure': True, 'value': '12345'}
```

То для использования add_cookie() и успешного добавление cookie, нужно находится на домене drive.google.com.

Но все сервисы google и многе другие сервисы, делают редиректы, и по этому зайти на конкретный список доменов и поддоменов для импорта всех cookie - нельзя.
Да и к тому-же это очень долго, загружать 10 страниц, для того что-бы импортировать cookie.

В общем, мой вопрос таков: 
Можно ли обойти данное ограничение?

Может есть какой-нибудь аналог selenium, или какой нибудь другой метод?